# How to validate Video in node js based on it's length and quality

Tags: node.js, validation, express, video-streaming

I have been searching through net, how to upload video and Validate it based on it's length and quality like 480 or 720 minimum. Moreover, If it does not have any adultery content. My development environment is Node along with express framework in it. I am looking for ward for nay kind of maybe plugin suggestion that I could work out my self how to configure it with my application. Any kind of suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Video file has metadata, which should be able to read from file header.

Comment: Thank you, Let me look into it, Could you guide me if there is any plugin in node with which I could access that metadata, Though I do understand your answer and find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Information like length of the video or resolution is part of the file's metadata. To be able to read metadata of some file type, you need specific library.

This should help for videos:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmetadata

At least for lenght and quality. As for the content - you would need to process binary data through some content detection algorithm, combined with machine learning probably :) I don't think there is anything out of the shelve for that.

Comment: I am looking into it Peter, Will let you know the update.